# JQuery DataTable Pagination issue

Tags: css, jquery

I have created a dataTable and filling data inside the table using json object. My problem is in pagination i am *not getting the total number of pages*.

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
                    "bPaginate" : true,                     
                    "bLengthChange" : false,                        
                    "bFilter" : false,
                    "bSort" :true,
                    "bInfo" : false,
                    "bAutoWidth" : false
                });
```

Please help me in this issue...
Thanks in advance....
[image]

Comment: Maybe you have set to "display: none". Try to inspect the place where you expect it to appear

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the, "Showing 1 to x of n entries" below the table? If so try reading this:

http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/dom.html

If this isn't the problem, can you post a picture of what is wrong? DataTables should (by default) display the total number of pages from a JSON object